# Google Analytics API deviceCategory

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to use the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/) (v3) in [Google Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) to pull [Device Category](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=platform_or_device&jump=ga_devicecategory) information from Google Analytics.

Within Analytics under `Audience -> Mobile -> Overview` there is a `Device Category` section listing `'tablet', 'mobile' and 'desktop'`. I wish to pull these numbers into a Google Sheet that my script is attached to.

The code I believe I should be using is:
 `ga:deviceCategory==mobile (to pull mobile traffic)` and `ga:deviceCategory==tablet` to pull tablet traffic.

However, I receive the error:

> Invalid dimension or metric: ga:deviceCategory==desktop

I'm somewhat confused by this as Google's own documentation says that deviceCategory is a valid dimension

(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=platform_or_device&jump=ga_devicecategory)

If I remove the device type from the end ('ga:deviceCategory') I get the error:

> Unknown metric(s): ga:deviceCategory (line 43, file "Code")

This leads me to believe that I need to include the metric (which I believe is 'pageviews') beforehand. If this is the case, can someone show me how I pull in the figures for mobile/tablet traffic?

I am having no other issues pulling other aspects of my data. For example:

```
var impressions = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate, endDate, 'ga:visits').rows.toString();
```

works fine.

For reference, this is the full code I am using for device Category:

```
  // Get Mobile Visits, this is the number of visits from mobile devices
  var mvisits = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate, endDate, 'ga:deviceCategory==mobile').rows.toString();
      mvisits = mvisits;
```

I would be grateful for any assistance and please let me know if you require any more code from my script.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My app script is a bit rusty but your problem is your `==`  the dimension field is just a column you want to select.

```
var tableId  = 'ga:' + profileId;
var metric = 'ga:visits';
var options = {
    'dimensions': 'ga:deviceCategory',
    'filters': 'ga:deviceCategory==mobile'
    };
var report = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, startDate, endDate, metric,
  options);
```

What you need to do is add some `filters` instead.  If you think of this like a relational database this would be like saying

```
select deviceCategory, visits
from tableId  
where devicecategory == mobile
```

Remember you need to add a metric.

**Example**: shamelessly ripped from [Analytics service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/analytics) page.

Comment: Hi there, thanks very much for taking the time to get back to me regarding this. I understand your point about needing a metric so that I can then filter by device category. I will have another go now and see if I can get it working.

Comment: The issue I am having (after thinking about your code and trying to apply it to my current script) is that the script is expecting 'ga:' where you have included 'metric,options' (in var report = .....)

Presumably this is due to the code Analytics.Data.Ga.get beforehand

Comment: metric and options are just variables that have been declared.   check the page I linked its Googles documentation.

Comment: I understand that but I wonder if Analytics.Data.Ga.get is the problem here. It sounds like the script is expecting ga: but isn't getting this, despite declaring the variables beforehand.

I apologise, I'm not a programmer so I don't know all the technical terms!

Comment: Hi DalmTo, just to let you know I have got it working via your instructions. Thank you so much for your help!