# Build a device category chart with Google Analytics Reporting API v4

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-reporting-api

I am trying to build a multiple line chart with Google Analytics Reporting API v4.

A chart where I have a line for each device (Desktop/Tablet/Mobile) by session count by day.

But for now all I can get is this:

[image]

And my code is:

```
<div id="chart-1-container"></div>

<script>
 gapi.analytics.ready(function () {
    var dataChart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        query: {
            'ids': 'ga:XX', // <-- Replace with the ids value for your view.
            'start-date': '7daysAgo',
            'end-date': 'yesterday',
            'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
            'dimensions': 'ga:deviceCategory'
        },
        chart: {
            'container': 'chart-1-container',
            'type': 'LINE',
            'options': {
                'width': '100%'
            }
        }
    });
    dataChart1.execute();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You may want to check the example using V4 as shown in the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration) in expressing more complicated segment definitions by using the `segments` field which includes [Dynamic Segments](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/migration#segments) object. As shown in the example, you can combine conditions and sequences in a segment. Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have checked it but did not found a way to solve the question :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer of this question - [Google Analytics API deviceCategory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538176/google-analytics-api-devicecategory) - I finally found the problem.

To get a specific chart based on a category like mobile, the data is build based on filters and not on dimensions like I was trying to achieve:

```
<div id="chart-1-container"></div>

<script>
    gapi.analytics.ready(function () {
        var dataChart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            query: {
                'ids': 'ga:XX', // <-- Replace with the ids value for your view.
                'start-date': '7daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday',
                'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
                'dimensions': 'ga:date',
                'filters': 'ga:deviceCategory==mobile' // <-- Filter the category here
            },
            chart: {
                'container': 'chart-1-container',
                'type': 'LINE',
                'options': {
                    'width': '100%'
                }
            }
        });

        dataChart1.execute();

    });
</script>
```

And that's it:

[image]