# Google Optimize API - Get device segmentation

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client, google-optimize

I managed to access the Analytics V3 API and list all my experiments.

While creating the experiment in Google Optimize, I can add a segmentation on the device category (eg. mobile, deskop...)

However, when accessing my experiments from the API, I can't seem to be able to access to this information.

I've seen that the GA API allow to get deviceCategory data but it seems more related to the Analytics campaigns: [Google Analytics API deviceCategory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538176/google-analytics-api-devicecategory).

I don't know if they are related with the experiments.

**Has somebody already managed to get the device information for the experiments?**

Thanks.